# FreeRADIUS Version 3.0.13 - Failed to find 'Auth-Type EAP' section

Tags: freeradius

I trying to setting FreeRadius on my AWS Linux. It was working when I first set it up or atleast I was able to active it. However, after I reboot the Radius server and try to start it, I get the following error:
/etc/raddb/mods-enabled/eap[14]: Failed to find 'Auth-Type EAP' section.  Cannot authenticate users.
/etc/raddb/mods-enabled/eap[14]: Instantiation failed for module "eap"

I opened the eap file and updated default_eap_type = peap. I also enabled MS-CHAP v2 which I also enabled but now, I keep getting this error for eap which I do not want users to be authenticated through EAP.

Can anyone provide any guidance please?

Answer (score 6):

The `peap` module requires the `inner-tunnel` site.

I fixed with:

```
ln -s /etc/freeradius/3.0/sites-available/inner-tunnel /etc/freeradius/3.0/sites-enabled/
```

This was a fresh FR3 install on Ubuntu 20.04.